# How to access instance variable from ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named User and in its index.html.erb file, has a link which calls an ajax request responsible for retrieving user's authenticated radars. There it is:

```
//user.js
function retrieve_radars() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "/radars",

    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}

#app/controllers/radars_controllers.rb
def index
  user    = current_user;
  @radars = Radar.where(:user_id => user.id)
  @radars
end
```

How could I iterate @radars instance variable in "users/index.html.erb", after the success ajax response? I would like to do something like this:

```
<% unless @radars.nil? %>
  <table>
  <% @radars.each do |radar| %>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><%= radar.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//user.js
function retrieve_radars() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "/radars",

    success: function(data) {
      //load the response from radar#index into the div (or any other element
      $("#my_div").html(data); 
    }
  });
}

#app/controllers/radars_controllers.rb
def index
  user    = current_user;
  @radars = Radar.where(:user_id => user.id)
  render :partial => "radars", :layout => false #render partial. 
end

#app/views/radars/_radars.html.erb create partial file
<% unless @radars.nil? %>
  <table>
  <% @radars.each do |radar| %>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><%= radar.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It worked! Just one detail on your code, I had to create _radars.html.erb partial file, instead of _radar.html.erb :)

Comment: My bad, i wrote it from my iPad :)